# Non-SharePoint Owner receiving Access Requests

Tags: sharepoint-online, permissions, access-requests

I am a fairly new SharePoint owner for my group SharePoint and I have not been able to find an answer to this issue.  I have configured the settings set up for access requests to send me and email, and I do receive these when a request comes through from our SharePoint.

There is another user on the group SharePoint that often receives access requests for our SharePoint.  These requests only go to him and do not show up in the Access requests for me to approve on SharePoint.  These requests do not have a reason for requesting access, and often the think they are trying to request access to tells me I do not have access (I think the files have maybe been deleted).

Does anyone have an explanation as to what might be going on?  The person on my team receiving these emails is annoyed to be receiving them and I would like to fix the issue.  I would also like to be able to manage all requests for access to our site that are coming through.

Thanks!

Comment: Is there a specific list/library that he is getting access requests for, or is it for the entire group site?

Comment: Both of you are getting access requests emails for same sharepoint site or two different sites/subsites??

Answer (score 0):

Follow below steps to allow access requests to a single user for your SharePoint site:

1. Go to **Settings > Site Permissions**.
2. Click **Advanced permission settings**.
3. On the Permissions tab, click **Access Request Settings**.
4. Select Radio button near input text box with placeholder "e-mail address" and put your email address in text box.
5. Click **Save**.

[image]

**Reference**: [Set up and manage access requests](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/set-up-and-manage-access-requests-94b26e0b-2822-49d4-929a-8455698654b3).

Answer (score 0):

I have already added my email as the email address for requests to come to, and have been getting these request for 6 months or more.

He is getting access requests to subpages on the SharePoint that I am the owner of.